# Stubbing Custom TagLib method in Controller Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, grails, mocking, taglib, stubbing

I have a method in a custom taglib like so:

```
def deleteAction = {attrs ->
    def id = attrs['id']
    def type = attrs['type']
    def clazz = attrs['class']
    def html = new MarkupBuilder(out)
    html.span(class: "${clazz} ui-icon ui-icon-trash {id:'${id}'}")
}
```

I have a controller that uses this method and I'm trying to stub it out for a unit test, so I have the following:

```
def mockMyTagLib = mockFor(MyTagLib)
    mockMyTagLib.demand.deleteAction(1) {id, type, clazz ->
    def html = new MarkupBuilder(new StringWriter())
    html.span(class: "${clazz} ui-icon ui-icon-trash {id:'${id}'}")
}

controller.metaClass.mn = mockMyTagLib.createMock()
```

But I keep getting the following:

> No more calls to 'deleteAction'
>   expected at this point. End of
>   demands.

Am I doing something wrong here?  Here is it's actual usage in the controller:

```
"${mn.deleteAction(id: it.id, type: 'bookProduct', 'class': 'del-book-product')}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is from [Testing - Reference Documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/9.%20Testing.html)

> ... You then specify the name of the
>   method that you want to mock with an
>   optional range as its argument. This
>   range determines how many times you
>   expect the method to be called, so if
>   the number of invocations falls
>   outside of that range (either too few
>   or too many) then an assertion error
>   will be thrown. If no range is
>   specified, a default of "1..1" is
>   assumed, i.e. that the method must be
>   called exactly once.

You've specified demand.deleteAction(1) which means that the method must be called once and only once.

Also, if you want, you can always set your mock to be loose by specifying it as the second parameter in mockFor (defaults to strict)

```
mockFor(class, loose = false)
```

Comment: Grails tells me that it can't find the property "loose" when I define mockFor(Class, loose = false).  However, I modified my demand until I got it to work using a range 1..3. (why it needs it 3 times I still need to figure out).  So I'm past that, but getting a new error.  I suspect it has nothing to do with this, so I believe you've solved my problem.  I'm going to get it working 100% and if it truly isn't still a related issue, you'll get the bounty and I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: Good Luck! I hope you work through your new issues. Strange that the loose isn't working for you. Should just be mockFor(MyClass, false)  Javadocs here: http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/test/GrailsUnitTestCase.html